# Blank grey screen at login until you enter the command line and return?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, login, display

This seems a strange promlem. I've got used to it and found away around it but it certainly shouldn't be happening. Every time I get to the login screen, the screen is just grey with the mouse cursor and nothing else. To see it, I have to enter the command line by Ctrl+Alt+F1 then quit it and the screen appears. I actually know that the computer is at the stage to log in as i can just type my details in at the black screen, and then i have to do enter and quit the command line when it is on my invisible desktop.

I first thought it had a problem detecting my monitor so I got another spare monitor out and strangely when i use two, the one using DVI (not my main monitor), always comes up with the login screen. And to make things more confusing, my main monitor that i normally use on its own then also always shows the purple ubuntu background with the logo in the middle. When logged on, the other monitor always seems to be seen as the main one which I didn't want to be the case. I had to manually my other as the main screen after login every time in the nvidia settings.

Anyhow, when switching back to just my main monitor, weather it is with DVI or HDMI, it is still always this blank grey screen at the login. To me it suggests that after I see all the boot up information, the PC then maybe thinks another monitor is connected or something? Once I'm logged in and I've done what I said earlier, this one monitor is perfectly reliable, but it seems an odd issue.

Any advice on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Laptop or desktop? If laptop try the keys that let you select monitor 1 and see if that helps.

Comment: It is a desktop computer, but the behaviour makes it understandable why you implied it may be a laptop. It seems to be thinking I have another visible monitor or something. But no matter how long i leave it after logging in at the blank screen, it still won't change from this grey screen unless i enter and quit the command line. Don't even need to log in there which makes it even more strange.

Comment: I do have a very strange little computer myself. It has a video chip set on the motherboard but no connector to attach a monitor, It has an actual video card as well.  Windows has no problems but in Ubuntu I had to go into the monitor setup and turn off the motherboard monitor for the actual monitor to work. Took a while to find that. Maybe look for something similar?

Comment: Mine isn't an unusual set up though. My graphics card is the GTX 1650 and obviously that is separate to the motherboard. But as I see the mouse cursor, it isn't like it doesn't realise the monitor is there, it just seems to be sending it the wrong, or not enough information.